# Info Panel Missing

Tags: interface

the Info Panel is Missing. I need it back.

The thing on the top marked with (1):

[image]

Comment: you can simply restore it by setting the "info" panel into one of the areas.  Then, you can reset file > "load factory settings" and then "save startup file".

Comment: Didn't realize it was simply a panel, thanks! No idea what your 2nd sentence is about though.

Comment: 2nd sentence was just in case you found the same missing info panel at a new blender startup. In that case somehow you could have saved a "wrong layout" as default. So, as said, using  file > "load factory settings" and then "save startup file" you could reset blender interface at default "factory" settings.

Comment: I see... I run blender on three monitors. So If I close the windows in the wrong order everything gets screwed up when I reopen the file.

Comment: I never used more than one monitor but blender preferences must be explicitly saved (file menu) to survive a program restart, usually.